# Relationship one to one in GridView in asp.net C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I have the following GridView in my project:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="329px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="imie" HeaderText="imie" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="imie" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="nazwisko" HeaderText="nazwisko" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="nazwisko" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="idz" HeaderText="idz" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="idz" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="idp" HeaderText="idp" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="idp" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ids" HeaderText="ids" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ids" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="ProjektZaliczenieKoncowy.DBClassesDataContext" EntityTypeName="" OrderBy="id" Select="new (id, imie, nazwisko, idz, idp, ids)" TableName="pracownicies">
    </asp:LinqDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

In field "idz" I want to show the date from the column "Zawod" in the table "Zawody" where idz = id. It should be a one to one relationship.

Here's my database diagram:
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVwfC.jpg)

It's probably easy but I can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a stored procedure in your database which gets you all the columns you need with the one "Zawod" in the table "Zawody" where idz = id. After that you call this stored procedure with c#.
In your code you should have object which represents the entities from the database. You get the information from the database parse it to an object and after that you bind your list of these object to your gridview and there you can get the column you want from the other table.
If you want to do it without a stored procedure you can just write manually the text of the query and pass it as SQLCommand the continuation is the same anyway so the stored procedure is preferable.